# filesavedialog.showdialog hangs in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, c#-3.0, windows-installer

I am making custom setup project for msi.
There is very strange problem in one of the windows while installation goes. there is a show dialog call on click of a button. the installer is running fine on XP but on win 7 installer goes to not-responding and never comes back.
Below is the piece of code i am using for showing the dialog:

```
private void btnSetFileLocationWS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Set WS Log File Path";
    saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "log";
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Log files (*.log)|*.log|Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 0;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;  

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        txtFilePathWS.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
    btnNextWSLogging.Enabled = EnableDisabledNextWSLoggingButton();
}
```

Anybody??

Answer (score 0):

The MSI is running under an account which doesn't have access to the desktop. [This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/a32869e9-56b3-446d-aef2-68ffbf83142b) suggests a possible workaround, setting [AutoUpgradeEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.autoupgradeenabled.aspx) to false.

To fix it properly, you need to set [msidbCustomActionTypeNoImpersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa368069) in your MSI, for which you will need to use the [Orca MSI editor](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905).